# Length of Line Between Concentric Circles Based on Skew of Line to Circles

Tags: circles, angle, tangent-line

Thanks in advance for reading my question.  I have been thinking of this all day and I am stumped and hoping you can help.

I want to calculate the length of a line between two points on concentric circles.  [Please reference the drawing I provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvMrX.png).  I want to find x.  Assuming you know R1 and R2, as well as the skew angle of the line relative to the outer circle, is there a formula or way to determine the length of x?

One more thing, I am looking for a solution that does not use coordinates.

I hope you all can help!!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Referring to the above diagram, we have $$CD = R_1\sin\alpha \\ AD = R_1\cos\alpha \\ BD^2 = R_2^2-CD^2 \\ AB = AD - BD \\
\therefore AB = R_1\cos\alpha-\sqrt{R_2^2-R_1^2\sin^2\alpha}.$$ If the quantity under the radical is negative, then the line doesn’t intersect the inner circle.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.